# C++ Trying to implement a Matrix

Tags: c++, matrix

Firstly, I'm new to C++. I'm trying to implement a Matrix in C++.
I saw this:
https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Matrix-Classes-in-C-The-Source-File/

And i was trying to implement a construtor that would allow the user to create a matrix by using, as arguments, the vector of vectors. (IDK if that is possible).

```
template <typename T> class Matrix 
{
private:
    vector<vector<T>> content;
    unsigned _rows;
    unsigned _columns;

public:
    Matrix(unsigned rows, unsigned columns)
.
.
.
    Matrix(vector <vector<T>> a) {
        this->content = a;
    }
.
.
.
};
```

The goal was to create the matrix through this:

```
Matrix<double> m({ {1,2,3},{4,5,6} });
```

As I said, I don't know if it is possible or even correct. Any help would be truly appreaciated, even if it is just a good practise advise. Thank you in advance.

Edited:
I clearly had a mistake on the constructor, but now when i try to display it:

```
 Matrix<double> m3({ { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } });
    m3.display();
```

It returns nothing

Comment: What's your question? Please [edit] your question to include a specific question.

Comment: Why is the loop used, why not assignment content = a?

Comment: Sm, you're right... it was a clear mistake of mine... although now, when i try to display the matrix when using that constructor it returns nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could just assign a to Matrix.content, if you want it in a constructor it would be:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
private:
    vector<vector<T>> content;
    unsigned _rows;
    unsigned _columns;

public:
    Matrix(vector<vector<T>> a)
    {
        this->content = a;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solve. Bassicaly i was implementing the construtor in a bad way and displaying was not working it that after.

```
void display() {
    for (int i = 0; i < content.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < content[i].size(); j++)
            cout << content[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
};
```